# How to use loop to display looped information all at once? Functionality Issue

Tags: c++, loops, random, grid, coordinates

I am learning C++ and would like some **help with functionality** for my code below.
Quick summary/usage of my code: Program is to display randomized (x,y) coordinates and then print out the coordinates in a grid.

I got everything to work regarding randomizing (x,y) coordinates and then displaying their grid location.

**The problem** I am having is my code displays a separate grid for each coordinate instead of showing ALL coordinates on the same grid. [I attached a picture of my current output below].

I know this is a functionality issue.. but I am having trouble thinking of how to manipulate my loops so that the coordinates can be displayed first, followed by ONE grid with all the coordinates on it... I hope this makes sense.

Snippet of my code:

```
//Note: value of n and k is given by user earlier in the code
vector<vector<int> > vec( n , vector<int> (n));
cout << "\nGrid with city locations:\n";
for(i=0; i<k; i++) {
    //random select int coordinates (x,y) for each K(cities) 
    x = rand() % n + 0; 
    y = rand() % n + 0;
    arrCity[i] = i;

    //display coordinates for city 1..city2.. etc
    cout << "City " << arrCity[i] <<": (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;

    //display cities on grid
    for (int rows=0; rows < n; rows++) {
        for (int columns=0; columns < n; columns++) {
            if ((rows == y) && (columns == x)) {
                cout << "|" << (i);
            } else {
                cout << "|_";
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Current Output:

[image]

As you can see there's a separate grid for each 'city coordinate'

Comment: You are drawing the grid inside the loop where you randomize the cities, this is why it draws multiple times. 

You need randomize the cities and store the city number and  x,y, coordinates, for example in a vector or array of  structs. Then when drawing the grid check if that cell location matches a city. If it does then draw the correct city number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all city coordinates in order to display them on a single grid print. 
In the code below I changed a few things in order to hopefully address your problem.

- I have moved all city-related data into a structure
- Then all cities are initialized before the grid output
- When printing the grid, we have to search all cities if their coordinates match the current position, if so, we print the corresponding index.

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/9563g)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct City
{
    int index;
    int x, y;

    City(int index_, int x_, int y_)
        : index(index_), x(x_), y(y_)
    { }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int k = 6;

    std::vector<City> arrCity;
    arrCity.reserve(k);

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        arrCity.emplace_back(i, rand() % n, rand() % n);

    std::cout << "\nGrid with city locations:\n";

    for (int k = 0; k < arrCity.size(); k++)
        std::cout << "City " << arrCity[k].index << ": (" << arrCity[k].x << "," << arrCity[k].y << ")" << std::endl;

    //display cities on grid
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++) {
            int w = -1;
            for (int k = 0; k < arrCity.size(); k++)
                if ((i == arrCity[k].y) && (j == arrCity[k].x))
                    w = k;

            if (w >= 0)
                std::cout << "|" << arrCity[w].index;
            else
                std::cout << "|_";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to track which cells already has been visited. That's why you need to take another array which stores the cells that are already visited and by which value.

```
int vis[n][n];
memset(vis, -1, sizeof vis);

for(i=0; i<k; i++) {
    //random select int coordinates (x,y) for each K(cities)
    x = rand() % n + 0;
    y = rand() % n + 0;
    arrCity[i] = i;
    vis[x][y] = i;

    //display coordinates for city 1..city2.. etc
    cout << "City " << arrCity[i] <<": (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;

    //display cities on grid
    for (int rows=0; rows < n; rows++) {
        for (int columns=0; columns < n; columns++) {
            if (vis[rows][columns] != -1) {
                cout << "|" << (vis[rows][columns]);
            } else {
                cout << "|_";
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is not a very optimal solution, since you will be wasting memory with the `int vis[n][n]` for unused elements. Also, it is still not printing all on a single grid.